# VS Code Installed using snap but its not showing

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, configuration, detection

VS Code was installed in Kali Linux but I remove it using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge code

sudo apt autoremove
```

as I need to install snap because it automatically updates software then I install snap using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install snapd
```

after all this I type the following commands to install vscode:

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```

but after all this. vs code isn't available in the applications menu and also can't detect using

```
code --version
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if vs code is in the Snap installed list by running command

`snap list`

If it is in the list ,  try Running

`snap run code`

Comment: after executing this command vscode opened just like "code ."

Answer (score 1):

You download and install by manual

Download

```
wget https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/code_1.51.1-1605051630_amd64.deb
```

Give full permissin

```
chmod 777 code_1.51.1-1605051630_amd64.deb
```

Install

```
dpkg -i code_1.51.1-1605051630_amd64.deb
```

Done ✅